# Undo a pull request

Tags: git, github

I have raised a pull request. One of my team member will review it, then I will merge it to master. But I forgot to do a change in one of the files. I want to undo the pull request, so that I can do the pending changes and raise a pull request. What should I do to revert the pull request raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just push the changes to existing PR.

Otherwise you can close it and open a brand new one.

Comment: How to add changes to PR? @DonCallisto

Comment: The PR will be updated when you push into the branch that the PR is related to.

Comment: Thank you @eftshift0. I was thinking, something extra needed to be done. I updated the code and committed. It just got appended. Thanks again